# TypeError: can't assign to property "_canInitEmulator" on "email@gmail.com": not an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, typeerror

i am using Firebase but when I try to make a reset pass word link this error ocour's . What is the reason behind it and how can I solve this error. I have tried using email as a object cause i thought that it would solve the problem .My code:

```
> ` const handleReset = async () => {

`console.log(email)`

await sendPasswordResetEmail(email);

toast("reset password email send")

}`
```